# pyparsing - performance tips for parallel logs processing

Tags: multiprocessing, pyparsing

I'm using a 2 processes Pool to parallel parse several log files,

```
po = Pool(processes=2)
pool_object = po.apply_async(log_parse, (hostgroup_sender_dir, hostname, host_depot_dir,        synced_log, prev_last_pos, get_report_rate), )

(curr_last_pos, remote_report_datetime, report_gen_rate) = pool_object.get()
```

However it's quite slow on the initial run,
~16min for about twelve ~20Mb files.

There won't be much of a problem in the next iterations, considering I'll parse the logs new bytes each 2 or 3 min,
but surely there's room for improvement on how I'm doing it on the first run.
Would pre-splitting the logs into several lower sized splices 
(so that pyparse won't have to allocate the entirety of the log at ounce into memory)
speed it up?

I'm still running it on a dual core dev VM,
but soon will have to migrate to a quad core physical Server (I'll try to get an extra quad-core CPU) and it may need to be able to manage ~50 logs.

A splice from the log,

```
log_splice = """
# XX_MAIN     (23143) Report at 2011-08-30 20:00:00.003    Type:  Periodic     #
# Report number 1790                                        State: Active      #
################################################################################
# Running since                  : 2011-08-12 04:40:06.153                     #
# Total execution time           :  18 day(s) 15:19:53.850                     #
# Last report date               : 2011-08-30 19:45:00.002                     #
# Time since last periodic report:   0 day(s) 00:15:00.000                     #
################################################################################
                            ----------------------------------------------------
                            |       Periodic        |          Global          |
----------------------------|-----------------------|--------------------------|
Simultaneous Accesses       |  Curr  Max Cumulative |      Max    Cumulative   |
--------------------------- |  ---- ---- ---------- |     ---- -------------   |
Accesses                    |     1    5          - |      180             -   |
- in start/stop state       |     1    5      12736 |      180      16314223   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
Accesses per Second         |    Max   Occurr. Date |      Max Occurrence Date |
--------------------------- | ------ -------------- |   ------ --------------- |
Accesses per second         |  21.00 08-30 19:52:33 |    40.04  08-16 20:19:18 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
Service Statistics          |  Success    Total  %  |   Success      Total  %  |
--------------------------- | -------- -------- --- | --------- ---------- --- |
Services accepted accesses  |    17926    17927  99 |  21635954   21637230 -98 |
- 98: NF                    |     7546     7546 100 |  10992492   10992492 100 |
- 99: XFC                   |    10380    10380 100 |  10643462   10643462 100 |
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
Services succ. terminations |    12736    12736 100 |  16311566   16314222  99 |
- 98: NF                    |     7547     7547 100 |  10991401   10992492  99 |
- 99: XFC                   |     5189     5189 100 |   5320165    5321730  99 |
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
"""
```

using pyparse,

```
unparsed_log_data = input_log.read()

#------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Define Grammars
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
integer = Word( nums )

# XX_MAIN     ( 4801) Report at 2010-01-25 06:55:00
binary_name = "# XX_MAIN"
pid = "(" + Word(nums) + ")"
report_id = Suppress(binary_name) + Suppress(pid)

# Word as a contiguous set of characters found in the string nums
year = Word(nums, max=4)
month = Word(nums, max=2)
day = Word(nums, max=2)
# 2010-01-25 grammar
yearly_day_bnf = Combine(year + "-" + month + "-" + day)
# 06:55:00. grammar
clock24h_bnf = Combine(Word(nums, max=2) + ":" + Word(nums, max=2) + ":" + Word(nums,     max=2) + Suppress("."))
timestamp_bnf = Combine(yearly_day_bnf + White(' ') + clock24h_bnf)("timestamp")

report_bnf = report_id + Suppress("Report at ") + timestamp_bnf

# Service Statistics          |  Success    Total  %  | 
# Services succ. terminations |       40       40 100 |   3494775    3497059  99 |
partial_report_ignore = Suppress(SkipTo("Services succ. terminations", include=True))
succ_term_bnf = Suppress("|") + integer("succTerms") + integer("totalTerms")
terminations_report_bnf = report_bnf + partial_report_ignore + succ_term_bnf

# Apply the BNF to the unparsed data
terms_parsing = terminations_report_bnf.searchString(unparsed_log_data)
```

Comment: Could you post the code for log_parse? There may be some easy performance optimizations to make in the grammar definition, which would translate directly to some faster parsing time.

Comment: most of the code and a log splice as example added. I must be doing something terribly wrong as I'm noticing a 500 fold decrease on the time it takes to process the same logs using the re module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would structure the parser around parsing a single log entry. This accomplishes 2 things:

1. it breaks up the problem into easily parallelizable chunks
2. it positions your parser to handle the incremental log processing after the initial backlog of log data has been processed

Your parallelizing chunk size is then a nicely packaged single item, and each process can parse the item separately (assuming that you don't need to carry forward any state or elapsed time info from one log message to the next).

**EDIT** (this question has morphed into more of a topic on pyparsing tuning...)

I've found that it is better to define low-level primitives that are built up using `Combine(lots+of+expressions+here)` using a pyparsing Regex expression. This usually applies to expressions like real numbers or timestamps, such as:

```
# 2010-01-25 grammar
yearly_day_bnf = Combine(year + "-" + month + "-" + day)
yearly_day_bnf = Regex(r"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}")

# 06:55:00. grammar
clock24h_bnf = Combine(Word(nums, max=2) + ":" + 
                       Word(nums, max=2) + ":" + 
                       Word(nums, max=2) + Suppress("."))
clock24h_bnf = Regex(r"\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.")
clock24h_bnf.setParseAction(lambda tokens:tokens[0][:-1])

timestamp_bnf = Combine(yearly_day_bnf + White(' ') + clock24h_bnf)
timestamp_bnf = Regex(r"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}")
```

No need to overdo, though. Things like `integer=Word(nums)` are already generating RE's under the covers.

Note that I also removed the results name from timestamp_bnf. I usually leave off the results names from the primitive definitions, and add them as I assemble them into higher-level expressions, so I can use the same primitive multiple times, with different names, like:

```
summary = ("Started:" + timestamp_bnf("startTime") + 
           "Ended:" + timestamp_bnf("endTime"))
```

I find that this also helps me organize my parsed structures.

Moving the results name to the higher expression also leads me to give the field a more descriptive name:

```
report_bnf = report_id + Suppress("Report at ") + timestamp_bnf("reportTime")
```

Looking at your grammar, you are not really cracking all of this report info, just extracting the report time from this line:

```
# XX_MAIN     (23143) Report at 2011-08-30 20:00:00.003
```

and 2 integer fields from this line:

```
Services succ. terminations |    12736    12736 100 |  16311566   16314222  99 |
```

Try this instead:

```
report_bnf = report_id + Suppress("Report at") + timestamp_bnf("reportTime")
succ_term_bnf = (Suppress("Services succ. terminations") + Suppress("|") + 
                        integer("succTerms") + integer("totalTerms"))
log_data_sources_bnf = report_bnf | succ_term_bnf

extractLogData = lambda logentry : sum(log_data_sources_bnf.searchString(logentry))

print extractLogData(log_slice).dump()
```

Pyparsing will always be slower than RE's, and it may be that a pyparsing parser in your case is just a prototyping stepping stone. I'm sure I can't get you 500X performance with a pyparsing parser, and you may just have to use the RE-based solution to process Mb's worth of log files.

Comment: Thank you so much for the patience to explain it this thoroughly Paul.
I'll test it further, but I do appreciate your tips and explanation.